# Message Driven Channel Adapter not polling message while application is redeployed into weblogic server

Tags: jms, spring-integration

After redeploying Spring Integration application in web logic server , the Messages are not getting lnto Message Driven Channel Adapter though Restarting Server the message are coming again into Spring integration app.
Using trace log  it is saying no message received though just sent message.
Even did full maven deployment- Stop-app -.Undeploy ->Deploy -.Start-app.

I am using Default message listener configuration along with message selector.
Below is config used-

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory"
    ref="userConnectionFactory" />      <property name="cacheConsumers"
    value="true" />         <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"
    />  </bean> 

<bean
    id="publishmessageListenerContainer"    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">       <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
            <property name="destination" ref="publishIncoming" /> 

<property
name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="20" />         <property
name="concurrentConsumers"    value="1" />          
name="autoStartup" value="false" />     
name="messageSelector" value="CMDTARGET='PUBLISH'" > </bean>
```

Message Driven Channel adapter-

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsInEldm"container="publishmessageListenerContainer"
    channel="IncomingELDMChannel"/>
```

Please let me know if this is bug or some missing configuration.

Comment: Please, consider to study this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It isn't clear what is your problem and there is really not enough info to determine what's going on. You messages might just not match that `selector`. Some DEBUG logs for the `org.springframework.jms` category would be helpful, too.

Comment: Message Driven Adapter saying message not recieved in trace log though message was sent. Also message selector is correct. Issue occurs only when we redeploy the application without server restart. After the server restart issue does not occurs.  Not sure why this is happening . We cannot afford server restart for every deployment and hot deployment is very much needed.